# Vue2 issue using computed property to filter nested v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an odd HTML setup that I need to loop through. I get my data in two parts from Firebase. There is a `categories` and a `businesses` set of data structured like so:

```
Businesses
    -UniqueFirebaseID
        cat: "food"

Categories
    -IniqueFirebaseID
        name: "food"
```

I then want to loop through my data like so (pardon the non-semantic markup):

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="cat in categories">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="business in filteredByCat">{{business.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to put together a computed property to filter. The one below represents what I'm trying to do but not sure how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
computed: {
    filteredByCat () {
      return this.businesses.filter((element) => {
        return element.cat.match(cat.name)
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party but I just wanted to add -for reference purposes- the [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results) from the official `Vue` guide that states this limitation and also the way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a method instead.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="cat in categories">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="business in filteredByCat(cat)">{{business.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

methods: {
    filteredByCat (cat) {
      return this.businesses.filter((element) => {
        return element.cat.match(cat.name)
      })
    }
  }
```

Alternatively you could use a computed to build the data structure you want to iterate.

```
computed:{
  businessesByCategory(){
    return this.categories.reduce((acc, category) => {
      acc[category] = this.businesses.filter(b => b.category == category)
      return acc
    }, {})
  }
}
```

And your new template would be

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(value, key) in businessesByCategory"> {{key}}
    <ul>
      <li v-for="business in value">{{business.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vmPoXW?editors=1010).